# How can I calculate an estimation of the form $P(Y>a)>b$?

Tags: probability-inequalities

Let $Y$ be some r.v. with known $E[Y]$ and $E[Y^2]$.

How can I calculate an estimate of the form
$$P(Y>a)>b$$

I thought this is an application of Chebyshev inequality, but I cannot quite see how to make

$$P(|X-E[X]| \ge a) \le \frac{Var(X)}{a^2}$$
$a>0$, to produce the estimate that I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I have a very similar (yet unsolved) problem, maybe I can help you with yours:

Let $E(X)\geq a \geq 0$, I claim that one then has the inequality $$P(X>a) \geq \frac{(E(X)-a)^2}{E(X^2)}.$$

**Proof:** Let $a\geq 0$ and write $X$ as $$X=X\cdot 1_{\{X>a\}} + X \cdot 1_{\{X\leq a\}},$$
where $1_{\{\cdot\}}$ is an indicator function.
We then have
$$E(X) = E(X\cdot 1_{\{X>a\}} + X \cdot 1_{\{X\leq a\}}) = E(X \cdot 1_{\{X\leq a\}}) +E(X \cdot 1_{\{X> a\}}).$$
while  $E(X \cdot 1_{\{X\leq a\}}) \leq a$, the cauchy schwarz inequalities yields
$$E(X \cdot 1_{\{X>a\}}) = E(|X \cdot 1_{\{X>a\}}|) \leq \sqrt{E(X^2)E(1_{\{X>a\}}^2)} = \sqrt{E(X^2)} \sqrt{P(X>a)}.$$

Combining the above arguments we then have:
$$ E(X)\leq a + \sqrt{E(X^2)}\sqrt{P(X>a)},$$
from which the inequality
$$P(X>a) \geq \frac{(E(X)-a)^2}{E(X^2)}$$
immediately follows.

Comment: While I find your answer useful, what confuses me is why doesn't this use Chebyshev inequality.

Comment: You can not use Chebyshev inequality, because this Chebyshev gives only an upper of the probability but you are searching for a lower bound.

Comment: I've seen Chebyshev used to derive lower bounds as well. E.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182540/use-chebychevs-inequality-to-find-a-lower-bound

Comment: Chebyshev Inequality reads $P(|X-E(X)|\geq a) = 1- P(|X-E(X)|<a)  \leq \frac{Var(X)}{a^2}$, hence you can derive an upper bound for the probability  for the event  $|X-\mu|\geq a$ and a lower bound for the event $|x-\mu|<a$. however, on  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Inequalities_for_bounded_variables) there is another lower bound given for bounded variables.